# Get PayPal Profile ID with user's email address

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm wondering if it's possible to look up a PayPal Recurring Payments Profile ID using the email address used to create the profile.

I'm aware of the GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails API call, but this call requires the Profile ID as a parameter. I need to look up the Profile ID with only the email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can use [TransactionSearch API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) to search for the required information using buyer's email address. You will get the associated ProfileIDs/Transaction ids for the buyer.

The response variable is `L_TRANSACTIONIDn`

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll be trying this out later today and let you know how it goes. Quick note, it looks like L_TRANSACTIONIDn is the merchant's transaction id and in order to actually get the Profile ID you would need to make another call GetTransactionDetails

Comment: Yeah this works, to get the profile ID you have to find the most recent L_STATUSn equal to Created that has not been cancelled and then the corresponding L_TRANSACTIONIDn with the same n value will give you the profile id